# nodejs cluster distributing connection

Tags: node.js, pm2

In [nodejs api doc](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html), it says

> The cluster module supports two methods of distributing incoming
>   connections.
>
> The first one (and the default one on all platforms except Windows),
>   is the round-robin approach, where the master process listens on a
>   port, accepts new connections and distributes them across the workers
>   in a round-robin fashion, with some built-in smarts to avoid
>   overloading a worker process.
>
> The second approach is where the master process creates the listen
>   socket and sends it to interested workers. The workers then accept
>   incoming connections directly.
>
> The second approach should, in theory, give the best performance. In
>   practice however, distribution tends to be very unbalanced due to
>   operating system scheduler vagaries. Loads have been observed where
>   over 70% of all connections ended up in just two processes, out of a
>   total of eight.

I know PM2 is using the first one, but why it doesn't use the second? Just because of `unbalnced distribution`? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second may add CPU load when every child process is trying to 'grab' the socket master sent.